# Input on Visual force page form with Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, case

I am new to visual force pages and have gone through some trailheads but am stuck on this part. Basically I want to submit an id from a contact record on the page and from that I want to query my salesforce cases for that contact and display them on the page. What I have included below works exactly the way I want except I have hardcoded the accountId. What I want to do is be able to get the value from the user in my controller, make a new SOQL statement to get the accountId and then execute my statement. What do I need to change on my visual force page to get input from the user and then display my info?

Below is my visual force page:

```
<apex:page controller="CaseListController">
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Case List" id="case_list">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! cases }" var="ct">
        <apex:column value="{! ct.CaseNumber }"/>
        <apex:column value="{! ct.Owner.Name }"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class CaseListController {
public List<Case> getCases() {
String accountId = '0010400001234ABEEY';
List<Case> results = Database.query(
    'SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Owner.Name ' +
    'FROM Case ' +
    'Where AccountId = :accountId'
);
return results;
}

}
```

Comment: By the way, you only need Database.query(string) for dynamic queries, such as selecting variable columns. In your case, you can simply write `Case[] results = [SELECT CaseNumber, Owner.Name FROM Case WHERE AccountId = :accountId];` It's considered a best practice to an inline query (as demonstrated here) whenever possible, as they are compile-time checked for syntax errors and are generally more capable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to read a parameter from the URL:

```
String accountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
```

Which you then place into the URL:

```
/apex/myPage?id=0010400001234ABEEY
```

To make it dynamic, you can use URLFOR in different areas. For example, in a formula, you might use:

```
URLFOR($Page.myPage, null, [id=Account.Id])
```

Edit:

To allow a user to select an Id (or even better, a record), you can add a field. I'd start with something like this:

```
public class CaseListController {
  public Contact filterContact { get; set; }
  public Case[] caseRecords { get; set; }
  public CaseListController() {
    filterContact = new Contact();
    loadCaseList();
  }
  public void loadCaseList() {
    caseRecords = [SELECT CaseNumber, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE AccountId = :filterContact.AccountId];
  }
}
```

For which you'll want to use `apex:inputField`:

```
<apex:page controller="CaseListController">
    <apex:form>
        Search: <apex:inputField value="{!filterContact.AccountId}">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!loadCaseList}" />
        </apex:inputField>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Case List" id="case_list">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!caseRecords}" var="ct">
                <apex:column value="{! ct.CaseNumber }"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Owner">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!ct.OwnerId}" />
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Note that we must use the Id field to save the value, so we use OwnerId instead of Owner.Name. The name will automatically be displayed.

Comment: will this allow the user to enter it on the page? Basically I just want a field on the visual force page where they can enter the id. Then the lookup will happen in the controller and post the result back to the page

Comment: @MarkC5000 No, it sounds like I misunderstood your question. Give me a minute.

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox

Comment: for some reason I keep getting the following error: Unknown property 'CaseListController.cases' . Do I need to include some submit button to the form so the user types the value, submits the form and then the data displays?

Comment: @MarkC5000 I meant to write CaseList there, actually. Edited.

Comment: for some reason it's still not saving. This time it says Unknown property 'CaseListController.caseList' which happens on line 0.

Comment: @MarkC5000 I had renamed the variable, then forgot about it.  The variable name in the markup needs to match the variable name in the controller. I actually built this code in my org to make sure I cleaned up all my mistakes. Give the new version a try.

Comment: ok that makes sense and it works now. Thanks again